# If statement issue - shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

```
 <div class="blog-custom-featured-section">
  {% for article in blog.articles limit: 3 %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
    <div class="journal-featured-post">
      <img src="{{ article | img_url: '633x480' }}">
      <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
    </div>
  {% else %}
    <div class="journal-recent-post">
      <h3>RECENT</h3>
      <img src="{{ article | img_url: '332x187' }}">
      <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.blog-custom-featured-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.journal-featured-post .journal-recent-post {
  width: 50%;
}
.journal-featured-post {
  margin-left: 151px;
  margin-right: 172px;
  margin-top: 94px;
}
.journal-recent-post {
  margin-right: 112px;
}
.journal-recent-post h3 {
  margin-top: 63px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-family: Graphit-Medium;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.journal-featured-post img {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 633px;
  max-width: 633px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 480px;
  max-height: 480px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.journal-recent-post img {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 332px;
  max-width: 332px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 187px;
  max-height: 187px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.journal-featured-post h1 {
  margin-top: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 85px;
  font-family: Graphit-Light;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 43px;
}
```

I have also made it into a code pen or at least the structure: https://codepen.io/alexmciver/pen/qBPNKpj

By the way, this is going to be a Shopify section hence the liquid.

What I am confused by is that it should work and I know the pure HTML one that I created on codepen works. I have tried adding extra if statements and had no luck

Comment: what you get from the liquid code?

Comment: @CharlesC. how can I send you a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I was able to finally solve it, it took a while but nevertheless I got there in the end.

One thing I have learnt though is liquid conditionals are complicated and also why does Shopify have to be unique and use elseif rather than else if like most other programming languages use?

Anyway, here’s my working solution:

```
    <section class="journal-article-top-ctn brick--margin  wrapper--brick">
  {% for article in blog.articles limit: 3 %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
      <div class="journal-featured-post first-article">
        <img src="{{ article | img_url: '633x480' }}">
        <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
      </div>
    {% elsif forloop.last %}
        <section class="journal-recent-post last-article">
          <img src="{{ article | img_url: '332x187' }}">
          <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
        </section>
     </div>
    {% else %}
      <div class='small-articles-ctn'>
        <h3>RECENT</h3>
        <section class="journal-recent-post second-article">
          <img src="{{ article | img_url: '332x187' }}">
          <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
        </section>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
 </section>
```

And the CSS:

```
.journal-article-top-ctn{
  display:flex;
  margin-top: 94px;
  margin-bottom: 85px;
}
.journal-featured-post{
  width: 60%;
  padding-right: 121px;
}
.small-articles-ctn{
 width: 40%;
}
.blog-custom-featured-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.small-articles-ctn h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-family: Graphit-Medium;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.journal-featured-post img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 633px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 480px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.journal-recent-post img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 332px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 187px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.journal-featured-post h1 {
  margin-top: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 85px;
  font-family: Graphit-Light;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 43px;
}
.journal-recent-post h1 {
  font-family: Graphit-Light;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 29px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 341px;
}
```